# Open gmail message intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

I use this intent to open Gmail message but i think i need to add in extra some info about id and i don't know Keys for extra.

```
Intent gmintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
gmintent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.HtmlConversationActivity"); 
gmintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(gmintent);
```

to ZZZZZZZover9000

```
public class MessageListClickListner implements OnItemClickListener{

    private Context context;
    private List<Map<String, String>> groupOfChilds;

    public MessageListClickListner(Context context, List<Map<String, String>> groupOfChilds) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.groupOfChilds = groupOfChilds;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        if("sms".equalsIgnoreCase(groupOfChilds.get(position).get("TYPE"))){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/"+groupOfChilds.get(position).get("ID")));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Email subject");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of Email");
            sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));

/*          Intent gmintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
//          gmintent.putExtra("id", groupOfChilds.get(position).get("ID"));
            gmintent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.HtmlConversationActivity"); 
            gmintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(gmintent);*/
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Published solution at:
[How to open a particular message/conversation in the Gmail app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592745/how-to-open-a-particular-message-conversation-in-the-gmail-app/10895903#10895903)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Email subject");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of Email");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

The user will get to choose which email client to use.

Comment: strange, but the code throws an exception and with the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and without it

Comment: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK falg. Is this really what you want?

Comment: It would help to see the entire error.  Where are you calling this code? It shouldn't be in your onCreate().

Comment: it is in my onItemClickListner

Comment: @x90: Please add your code to the question, not to the answer.

Comment: Other examples I see use intent.setFlags() rather than intent.addFlags().  Does this make a difference for you?

Comment: with intent.setFlags() flag is the same exception

Comment: Maybe you should try a pendingIntent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gmintent.putExtra("key", "value");
```

Comment: :) I want to know exactly the names of keys