# Android 4.2.2 - GMail app not in intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

i try to send an email, using my galaxy nexus with android 4.2.2 and im missing the googlemail app in the chooser. every other app is availible.
same problem on nexus 7.

i read something about a bug, the googlemail app does not work with attachments, but i reduced the code to a minimum and the gmail app is still missing.

```
Intent mailer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mailer.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailer, "pls show gmail"));
```

also tried with "message/rfc822" as type, but same problem: no gmail app availible.

tried the same code on android 4.0.x and a device with cyanogen mod and android 4.2.2 , and everything works fine.

can anyone help me? are there any workarounds?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592745/how-to-open-a-particular-message-conversation-in-the-gmail-app/10895903#10895903 ?

Comment: just noticed: if i try to share an image or a url, the gmail app is still missing. submitted bugreport: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53599

Comment: @AlexFlorescu thanks for your link but it doesnt work for me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This works on my Nexus 7

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String aEmailList[] = { "myname@gmail.com" };
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my subject");
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myMessage);
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: got a nexus 7 test device today, and everything is working as intended. sadly not on my galaxy nexus and not on the nexus device from my customer :-(