# Can I open my email thread in Gmail App If I have id or threadId?

Tags: android, gmail-api

I am using gmail APIs in my android app and I am able to get id and threadId.So is there any way I can populate gmail using these ids.

Comment: how are you getting the threadId from user interaction in your android app?

Comment: Any update on this? This question specifically requests viewing in the Gmail App, not via a call to the API which the two answers suggest. Is it possible to link to Gmail through Android? Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592745/how-to-open-a-particular-message-conversation-in-the-gmail-app

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the `messageId` representing the message you want, you can simply use the [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)-operation to get the email. You could either do the request manually

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/<MESSAGE_ID>
```

or with the help of a library:

```
Message message = service.users().messages().get('me', messageId).execute();
```

If you want to get all the mails in the thread, [it is just as easy to do that also](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get).

Look at code examples and explore the API in the links I provided.

Comment: Yes I have the messageId but I want to see this message in GMAIL android App using this messageId.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw message in  following way This is in python but in Java it would be similar. I hope I answered what you are looking for.

```
def GetMimeMessage(service, user_id, msg_id):   
"""Get a Message and use it to create a MIME Message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    msg_id: The ID of the Message required.

  Returns:
    A MIME Message, consisting of data from Message.   """   
    try:
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format = 'raw').execute()

        print 'Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet']
        print 'keys ', message.keys()
        msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

        mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)

        return mime_msg   
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error

for i in range(0,len(th['messages'])):

    print 'snippent --- ', th['messages'][i]['snippet']
    id = th['messages'][i]['id']
    print 'id---', id
    msg = GetMimeMessage(service, 'me', id )
    pay = msg.get_payload()
    pay1 = pay[0]
    print 'msg --- ', pay1.get_payload()
```